# Javascript/ modules: installing canvas-capture

Tags: webpack, canvas, node-modules

canvas-capture is a wrapper around CCapture.js and ffmpeg.wasm to record the canvas as video (mp4).

In Github the step-by step installation says:

```
npm install canvas-capture
```

Then add this to your js file:

```js
import { CanvasCapture } from 'canvas-capture';

CanvasCapture.init(
  document.querySelector('canvas'),
  { showRecDot: true }
);
etc..
```

But this yields an error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "canvas-capture". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

So I try with this instead:

```js
import { CanvasCapture } from '../canvas-capture/dist/canvas-capture.js';
```

And now the file is found alright, but I get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../canvas-capture/dist/canvas-capture.js' does not provide an export named 'CanvasCapture'
```

So when I go and check the canvas-capture.js file, In the very first line of code, I see that it relies on webpack (that I don't use) and there is no function or class I can "export" in order to prevent the error message.
Many stuff is already using an "exports" instruction that I don't know anything about.

Here is the file:

https://github.com/amandaghassaei/canvas-capture/blob/main/dist/canvas-capture.js

So, is there a way to be able to get this to work (without using webpack) ?

I'm new to modules and bundlers, so getting my way through whatever webpack is doing in order to solve the problem is tricky for me.

Does this file pretty much imply that webpack HAS to be used to make this work or is there a way to work around the issue?

Here is the Github page of canvas-capture:

https://github.com/amandaghassaei/canvas-capture

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at line number 9 of [canvas-capture.js](https://github.com/amandaghassaei/canvas-capture/blob/main/dist/canvas-capture.js#L9) we can see:

```
root["CanvasCaptureLib"] = factory();
```

That means the module exposes itself as `CanvasCaptureLib` to the `root` and in a browser context root refers to the global `window` object.

If you now do something like:

```
import '../canvas-capture/dist/canvas-capture.js';
console.log(CanvasCaptureLib);
```

You will see an object with the properties `CanvasCapture`, `default` and `__esModule` logged to the console.

So to actually use the module and get the default exports (in this particular case) you have to do it like this:

```
import '../canvas-capture/dist/canvas-capture.js';
const { CanvasCapture } = CanvasCaptureLib;
console.log(CanvasCapture);
```